# How to pivot data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

| PK_ID | HEADER2 | HEADER3 | HEADER 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SEQ_NO | 1223910 | A |
| 2 | [SCRAP_TYPE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qblnP.png) | C | A |
| 3 | SCRAP_HIST_ID | 6306713 | A |
| 4 | LOT_TRANS_ID | 6306713 | A |
| 5 | LOT_NO | 231NB0012 | A |
| 6 | PROC_ID | CD | A |
| 7 | SEQ_NO | 1223911 | A |
| 8 | SCRAP_TYPE | C | A |
| 9 | SCRAP_HIST_ID | 6309120 | A |
| 10 | LOT_TRANS_ID | 6309120 | A |
| 11 | LOT_NO | 231NB0013 | A |
| 12 | PROC_ID | CD | A |
| ... | ... | .... | A |

I need to run the pivot with the table data above,

With the regularity of HEADER2, I want to pivot HEADER2 to column and HEADER3 to ROW, but I'm not sure how to set the criteria and rotate the pivot.

Different headers come in dynamically, and data comes in like the table above, so what should I do about this

The results are derived using switch case grammar, but one header and data are derived.

```
DECLARE @SN INT
DECLARE @ST INT
DECLARE @SH INT
DECLARE @LTI INT 
DECLARE @LT INT
DECLARE @PI INT 


SET @SN = 0
SET @ST = 0
SET @SH = 0
SET @LTI = 0
SET @LT  = 0
SET @PI = 0

SELECT TOP 10000 MIN(SEQ_NO) AS 'SEQ_NO', MIN(SCRAP_TYPE) AS 'SCRAP_TYPE', MIN(SCRAP_HIST_ID) AS 'SCRAP_HIST_ID' , MIN(LOT_TRANS_ID) AS 'LOT_TRANS_ID' , MIN(LOT_NO) AS 'LOT_NO', MIN(PROC_ID) AS 'PROC_ID'
FROM ( SELECT CASE WHEN HEADER2 ='SEQ_NO' THEN 'SEQ_NO' END AS SEQ_NO
            , CASE WHEN HEADER2 ='SCRAP_TYPE' THEN 'SEQ_NO' END AS SCRAP_TYPE
            , CASE WHEN HEADER2 ='SCRAP_HIST_ID' THEN 'SEQ_NO' END AS SCRAP_HIST_ID
            , CASE WHEN HEADER2 ='LOT_TRANS_ID' THEN 'SEQ_NO' END AS LOT_TRANS_ID
            , CASE WHEN HEADER2 ='LOT_NO' THEN 'SEQ_NO' END AS LOT_NO  
            , CASE WHEN HEADER2 ='PROC_ID' THEN 'SEQ_NO' END AS PROC_ID
            , CASE WHEN HEADER2 = 'SEQ_NO' THEN                             @SN +1
                   WHEN HEADER2 = 'SCRAP_TYPE' THEN                         @ST+1
                   WHEN HEADER2 = 'SCRAP_HIST_ID' THEN @SH + 1
                   WHEN HEADER2 = 'LOT_TRANS_ID' THEN @LTI + 1
                   WHEN HEADER2 = 'LOT_NO' THEN @LT + 1
                   WHEN HEADER2 = 'PROC_ID' THEN @PI + 1 END AS ROWNUMBER
       FROM #temptable
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT CASE WHEN HEADER2 ='SEQ_NO' THEN HEADER3 END AS SEQ_NO
            , CASE WHEN HEADER2 ='SCRAP_TYPE' THEN HEADER3 END AS SCRAP_TYPE
            , CASE WHEN HEADER2 ='SCRAP_HIST_ID' THEN HEADER3 END AS SCRAP_HIST_ID
            , CASE WHEN HEADER2 ='LOT_TRANS_ID' THEN HEADER3 END AS LOT_TRANS_ID
            , CASE WHEN HEADER2 ='LOT_NO' THEN HEADER3 END AS LOT_NO  
            , CASE WHEN HEADER2 ='PROC_ID' THEN HEADER3 END AS PROC_ID
            , CASE WHEN HEADER2 = 'SEQ_NO' THEN @SN+1
                   WHEN HEADER2 = 'SCRAP_TYPE' THEN @ST+1
                   WHEN HEADER2 = 'SCRAP_HIST_ID' THEN @SH + 1
                   WHEN HEADER2 = 'LOT_TRANS_ID' THEN @LTI + 1
                   WHEN HEADER2 = 'LOT_NO' THEN @LT + 1
                   WHEN HEADER2 = 'PROC_ID' THEN @PI + 1 END AS ROWNUMBER
       FROM #temptable
       ) SUB
```

[image]

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server - please don't add it in the title also.

Comment: Please show how the expected result looks like

Comment: I've revised my post, I'd appreciate it if you could revise the image link

Comment: you have multiple `LOT_NO` like `231NB0012` and `231NB0013` and you only wanted one of value ?

Comment: You want only one record? Don't want 1223911 as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @columns = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(HEADER2), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY HEADER2 DESC)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT HEADER2 FROM #temptable) AS Headers;

SET @sql = '
SELECT ' + @columns + '
FROM (
    SELECT HEADER2, HEADER3 FROM #temptable
) AS Source
PIVOT (
    MIN(HEADER3) FOR HEADER2 IN (' + @columns + ')
) AS PivotTable;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

The above queries dynamically identifies unique headers in the `HEADER2` column of `#temptable` table, and constructs a `PIVOT` query using those headers, and executes it through dynamic SQL. [Check the example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2bqJnEsk).

Comment: Consider this revision to pivot all data, not just return one record https://dbfiddle.uk/Bu53pHDo

Comment: I attempted to make the header count dynamic but out of my league. In this case the count is 6.

Comment: I got this far but can't get the count variable to work in place of 6 in constructed SQL statement https://dbfiddle.uk/Og6A9riN. Would rely on no gaps in PK_ID sequence.

Comment: If columns are added in #temptable, can I pivot dynamically?